# "Blank tabs" on Teams App update deployment (Teams Toolkit)

Tags: deployment, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

My Teams app:

- multi-tenant
- deployed using Teams Toolkit to Azure Storage, CDN enabled with a Custom Domain
- in alpha use by internationally distributed organisation (third party, not me), users around the world
- the app functionality works fine including multi-tenant
- in rapid development so frequent code updates. Very rare manifest updates.

Problem:

- I frequently update the app's code and deploy the update to Azure using Teams Toolkit
- when I do this users often report 'blank tabs' for a period of time, can be many hours. They see the tab menu but the tab contents are simply blank. Purging the CDN doesn't seem to help.
- seems most common using Teams desktop app but also reported using browser and mobile Teams app
- I think this may be an issue of code deployment .js files (each of which gets a new filename) not being available to the install, I can sometimes reproduce but very unreliably. Other times I can access the app, using a user account on the client's AAD, successfully from different locations (using a VPN to emulate location).

Previously the app's Custom Domain was managed on Cloudflare's proxy.

I disabled this and implemented Azure CDN.

Users continue to report the problem.

This is very poor user experience.

Does anyone have experience of this or hypotheses on what may be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to test one thing first:   manually deploy a new code change to Azure storage, with the same storage-CDN-custom domain setup.

See if this also causes the hours delay symptom.

By doing this, if the issue is reproducible, it may indicate that the Azure Storage-CDN configuration needs to be optimized.

Otherwise please share the result and it will help narrow down the root causes.

Comment: Thank you.

It happened again - the cause seems to be that the client has locally cached the index.html but not the css and js files it refers to. Upon a new deployment those files are deleted from cdn (newly deployed files have new names and are referred to by an updated index.html). So the client's index.html now refers to file URLs that do not exist and return a 404.

Comment: Hello - I manually uploaded a trivial code change (a version tag) to the existing source code filenames.

On 2 tests - one in my desktop Teams app on my usual UK IP using my developer tenant, and another loading the app as a customer's tenant user on a USA IP - the update looked to complete correctly within a few minutes of the upload.

So in this situation at this time I was unable to reproduce the problem - though I suspect it's to do with source file name changes and references to them.

Does that help?